# typeahead.js deduplicate between prefetch and remote datasources

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, duplicates, typeahead.js

I'm using typeahead.js with both prefetch and remote
http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#custom-templates

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var castDirectors = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: '../api/v1/search/people_typeahead',
  remote: '../api/v1/search/people_typeahead?q=%QUERY'
});

castDirectors.initialize();

$('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'cast-directors',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: castDirectors.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        empty: [
      '<div class="empty-message">',
      'no matching names',
      '</div>'
    ].join('\n'),
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p><a href="{{link}}">{{value}}</a></p>')
    }       
});
});
```

However, there are duplicated entries in the prefetch JSON and remote JSON. How can I dedup so that it only shows one entry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the [dupDector](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#options) option to your Bloodhound intitialisation code i.e. put the following code after "remote:" :

```
dupDetector: function(remoteMatch, localMatch) {
    return remoteMatch.value === localMatch.value;
}
```

You haven't included your JSON so I cannot be sure that the comparison being made in the code above is correct. This code will ignore duplicate values in the local and remote datasources.

Comment: No problems @IanLin. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Is this still an option? I can't find documentation for it anywhere other than old gists and SO posts. UPDATE: This is superceded by identify: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/946

Comment: @PeterP. yes, my answer was for an older version of Bloodhound. Thanks for the useful update.